# Problemas con el código Python de Google YouTube Update. Necesito Opiniones!

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, youtube-api

Llevo un par de días intentando hacer que este codigo funcione. Antes que nada decir que no tengo ni ídea de python, solo llevo dos o tres días con él, así que perdonenme si desmuestro mi ignorancia al expresarme.

El tema es que queria usar el código de python publicado por google para actualizar videos de YouTube y me está dando problemas.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update?hl=es-419

Se exacatamente donde está el problema pero no logro solucionarlo por mi falta de experiencia con python.

La función que me está causando problemas es esta (la he simplificado un poco para ir directamente al problema en cuestión):

```
def update_video(youtube, args):


  # Call the API's videos.list method to retrieve the video resource.
  videos_list_response = youtube.videos().list(
    id=args.video_id,
    part='snippet'
  ).execute()
  print ('Call the APIs videos.list method to retrieve the video resource')

  print(videos_list_response);


  # If the response does not contain an array of 'items' then the video was not found.
  if not videos_list_response['items']:
    print ('Video "%s" was not found.' % args.video_id)
    sys.exit(1)


  print ('Copiando todos los metadatos viejos del video')   
  videos_list_snippet = videos_list_response['items'][0]['snippet']

  print('Cambiando el Valor del título del video');  
  videos_list_snippet['title'] = "Título Nuevo"
  print(videos_list_snippet); 


  # Update the video resource by calling the videos.update() method.
  videos_update_response = youtube.videos().update(
    part='snippet',
    body=dict(
      snippet=videos_list_response,
      id=args.video_id
    )).execute()


  print('The updated video metadata is:\n' +
        'Title: ' + videos_update_response['snippet']['title'] + '\n')
```

cuando imprimo la respuesta de Youtube

```
print(videos_list_response);
```

Lo que obtengo son los metadatos actuales del video de esta forma (creo que es una lista con etiquetas o algo así)

```
{'publishedAt': '2018-04-15T23:40:19.000Z', 'channelId': 'xxxxx', 'title': 'Titulo Viejo', 'description': "Algo", 'defaultAudioLanguage': 'zxx'}
```

Cuando hago esto para remplazar el titulo viejo por el nuevo

```
  print('Cambiando el Valor del título del video');  
  videos_list_snippet['title'] = "Titulo nuevo"
  print(videos_list_snippet);
```

en principio parace que todo va perfecto porque lo que obtengo es esto

```
{'publishedAt': '2018-04-15T23:40:19.000Z', 'channelId': 'xxxxx', 'title': 'Titulo nuevo', 'description': "Algo", 'defaultAudioLanguage': 'zxx'}
```

El problema viene cuando intento ejecutar esto:

```
  # Update the video resource by calling the videos.update() method.
  videos_update_response = youtube.videos().update(
    part='snippet',
    body=dict(
      snippet=videos_list_snippet,
      id=args.video_id
    )).execute()
```

Si lo pongo así obtengo este error (Bat Request - The request metadata is invalid)

```
An HTTP error 400 occurred:
b'{\n "error": {\n  "errors": [\n   {\n    "domain": "youtube.video",\n    "reason": "invalidVideoMetadata",\n    "message": "The request metadata is invalid.",\n    "locationType": "other",\n    "location": "body"\n   }\n  ],\n  "code": 400,\n  "message": "The request metadata is invalid."\n }\n}\n'
```

Y Si lo pongo así, dandole exactamente los mismos datos que me dio YouTube:

```
  # Update the video resource by calling the videos.update() method.
  videos_update_response = youtube.videos().update(
    part='snippet',
    body=dict(
      snippet=videos_list_response,
      id=args.video_id
    )).execute
```

Obtengo este error (Bat Request - The request metadata specifies an invalid or empty video title)

```
An HTTP error 400 occurred:
b'{\n "error": {\n  "errors": [\n   {\n    "domain": "youtube.video",\n    "reason": "invalidTitle",\n    "message": "The request metadata specifies an invalid or empty video title.",\n    "locationType": "other",\n    "location": "body.snippet.title"\n   }\n  ],\n  "code": 400,\n  "message": "The request metadata specifies an invalid or empty video title."\n }\n}\n
```

Todo esto me lleva a pensar que pueden estar ocurriendo una de estas cosas.

1º- O estoy seteando mal los valores de **videos_list_snippet**

2º- YouTube me mandó **videos_list_response** en un formato incorrecto

3º- La función **youtube.videos().update()** está funcionando mal

Cualquier ayuda, sugerencia, u opinión me será de gran ayuda!!

Comment: He revertido tu cambio de título a "resuelto". En [es.so] se marca como resuelto algo aceptando una respuesta :)

Comment: Ok, perfecto!! El título es lo de menos!! Lo importante es que funciona... Me estaba volviendo loco con esto!! :-) Un Saludo!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He hecho esto y me ha funcionado!! :-)

```
  new_vars={'title': args.title, 'description': args.description, 'categoryId' : '10'} 


  # Update the video resource by calling the videos.update() method.
  videos_update_response = youtube.videos().update(
    part='snippet',
    body=dict(
      snippet=new_vars,
      id=args.video_id
    )).execute()
```

Tambien funciona si se hace así

```
  new_vars={}
  new_vars['title'] = args.title
  new_vars['description'] = args.description
  new_vars['categoryId'] = "10
```

Perfecto!!